# PHP Storing and Comparing Business Hours in Database

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I need to store business hours and compare them to see when I should update (day of the week) and to determine if they're open or closed currently.

Now the issue comes in that for some of my venues, the hours might be 8:00 PM - 2:00 AM, which means that I can't automatically assume the `Carbon::now()` would tell me they're closed the next day as it'll see that as 2:00 AM on the day that it's being run (the day before it currently is), so it would tell me they're closed.

I can't add a day to all of the closing times, as some close at 10 PM, 11 PM, or anything before 12:00 AM, which would again give me incorrect comparisons

What's the best way to store these times in the database so I can easily compare if the places are open or not?

Here's anything you need to know

`barDays` - Table I store these in

I use Laravel so all queries to the database are in Laravel, but the fields for `barDays` are as follows:

```
'day_id', 'bar_id', 'type', 'musicType', 'hours'
```

Hours are stored in the format of `X:XX AM/PM - X:XX AM/PM`, where X is an integer from 0-9 this was the cleanest that I know of to store them, I can't use TimeStamps due to the fact that these are weekly values and unlikely to change.

I use Carbon for my queries as it's built into Laravel

Thanks for any help guys, I have been busting my brain for the last 6 days trying to figure this out and I'm at a serious hump

- Zach

Comment: have you thought of just using two fields? 1 being `opening_time` and one being `closing_time`, then to see if the store is opened, just compare your current time variable to those to and see if it's within their range. Hope this helps!

Comment: It won't help, the problem isn't that I can't get the open/close times, the problem is that I can't determine if the now is between the two because they're technically separate days but not always

Comment: Have you tried separating into days? I mean handle one day per record, if the range spills to the next day for example an opening time that spans 10pm-2am can be represented using two records 22:00-23:59, 00:00 to 02:00, this way you can be sure of consistency across your records, that you can pick a single day and check for that, and that alone

Comment: They're already separated into days 0-6, how would I store the second record AND that days record? How would I quantifiably say that something spills over into the next day too?

Comment: The bar_id has to be repeated for the corresponding day: `bar_id 1, day_id 1` => `22:00-23:59`, `bar_id 1, day_id 2` => `00:00 - 02:00` In a nutshell if you query for that  day id 1, the opening hour is 22:00 - 23:59, but checking the second day you'll have 00:00-02:00 which is correct

Comment: I'll advice that you separate you hours to two fields e.g 'start', and 'end' that way you can query much easily

Answer (score 0):

I've built something slightly similar years ago.
My approach was to detach the opening hours from the venue table, given that most of them had 2 or 3 separate opening/closing hours per day i.e.:

- Office: from 9 AM to 1 PM from 2 PM to 6 PM,
- Bars: from 11AM to 2PM from 8PM to 23.59PM, from 12AM to 2am,

On DB it was something similar to:

```
Bars
id | name | type
1  | Bar1 | A
2  | Bar2 | B

bar_days
id | bar_id | day_id | music_type | start    | end
1  | 1      | 1      | Z          |  9.00 PM | 10.00 PM
2  | 1      | 1      | Q          |  2.00 PM | 11.00 PM
3  | 2      | 1      | X          |  8.00 PM | 9.00 PM
4  | 2      | 1      | Y          |  9.00 PM | 10.00 PM
5  | 2      | 1      | Z          | 10.00 PM | 11.59 AM
5  | 2      | 2      | Z          | 12.00 AM | 2.00 AM
```

If you have to check only for a single hour to decide if is open close, it should already work.

If you must check if the place is open for a time range the join became a bit more complex but is still feasible given that there should be no more than 2 opening hours are contiguous (midnight) with same music_type, day_id and bar_id.

To calculate the days to add when comparing dates coming from this table, you may use something similar to this:

```
<?php
$today = 2;
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
    $eventDay = ( $i+$today ) % 7;
    $daysToAdd = $eventDay - $today;
    $daysToAdd = $daysToAdd < 0 ? (7+$daysToAdd) : $daysToAdd;
    $format = "event day %d - today %d we should add %d\n";

    echo sprintf($format, $eventDay, $today, $daysToAdd);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: They're all the same type of venue though, so there's no going this route. Some just close at 11 and some close at 2

Comment: If we add a day of the week and the music type I think this schema might work, I'll try to change it

Comment: How do you know whether or not something is open from the previous day? What if a venue closes at 2, we account for that, but the venue also opens at 3 am?

Comment: The day of the week, day_id, should be different after midnight.
If there are no contiguous events and you are querying for a time range, you can either return only the valid events until closing time, or make the query fail, it's up to your needs

Comment: Is it possible to define a date range with Carbon and it'll intelligently add the day? or is there a library to do this?

Comment: Can I just add a day if the closing time is < the opening time?

Comment: I think it would work fine, depending on the strategy you choose
From DB: you can run a query that returns all the events using your current date as starting point (and day of the week to know where to start from, I will write it as a Union from [this day of the week] until [6] UNION [0] to [this day of the week - 1]), so you will return to your app a set of complete datetimes instead of only hours. In this case from PHP you'will forget about the recurrent definition of your problem and just check sequential datetimes coming with real days

Comment: On the other hands you can solve in a completely different manner, handling adding a X days to the start/end. 
Where X can be calculated in a way similar to the script I'm writing here

[daysToAdd](https://www.tehplayground.com/005qdJjxMiAs6FuU)